# Show images or video or text in ListView in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-videoview

I am trying to understand what would be best in case where you have a listView and normally set text content on a TextView. Sometimes there can be a photo type or video, but I still have a TextView in my row. What should be best, to have "just in case" an ImageView and an VideoView and show them when it's the case? Thinking of the performance as well. Being a custom adapter, the least of logic the faster the render.

This is my row xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <com.pubble.moderator.utils.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/author_icon"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_64dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/author_icon"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author_msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/author_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/author_icon"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/chat_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/author_name"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/author_name"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the custom adapter `extends ArrayAdapter<Chat> implements Filterable`

I have :

```
Linkify.addLinks(holder.msgTxt, Linkify.ALL);
holder.msgTxt.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
holder.msgTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

But if the content it's photo or video type, what is best to do? Hide `holder.msgTxt` and show an appropriate component that can consume the content? I just don't know, really. Any ideas are welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: if you have a know set of different layouts in your list, you can consider using different view types. (override getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType to indicate the types of your items). That allows you to use different layouts. However, if your layout is basically the same, except the image is visible or not, then using the same layout and changing the image visibility can be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView seems to be a good option.

Check this link :
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use Picasso library for showing images it let you load image asynchronously without affecting the performance